# Android Dropbox Datastore DbxTable.query getNull at first linked

Tags: dropbox, datastore

When Linked success first time,I used mTable.insert(accountsFields) to upload。 Before upload，

```
DbxFields queryParams = new DbxFields().set("uuid",accountsFields.getString("uuid"));
DbxTable.QueryResult results = mTable.query(queryParams);;
Iterator<DbxRecord> it = results.iterator();

if (it.hasNext()) {
DbxRecord firstResult = it.next();
if (firstResult.getDate("dateTime_sync").getTime() < accountsFields.getDate("dateTime_sync").getTime()) {

firstResult.setAll(accountsFields);
}

} else {
mTable.insert(accountsFields);
}
```

But，I get results null at first time and insert Duplicate same data。help me

Comment: Cross-linking with this question on the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=120636.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a timing bug. Everything in the Sync/Datastores SDK is asynchronous. Right after you link an account, the SDK starts to download data from the server. If you query immediately, you'll see nothing (since no data has yet been downloaded).

To solve your particular problem, it would probably be better to just use the UUID as the record ID. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/84/initializing-data-in-datastores-with-getorinsert for an example. Essentially this:

```
String uuid = ...;
DbxRecord record = table.getOrInsert(uuid, new DbxFields().set("foo", "bar"));
```

That way, you can never have duplicate records. If multiple users or the same user on multiple devices insert the same record, they'll all end up getting merged via conflict resolution, so you'll never have more than one record for that UUID on the server.

Comment: I know this is my design flaws。is there a way to know the data download is completed

Comment: And can  I custom the  record ID value.

Comment: Yes, you can use an observer on the datastore to see when the initial download is complete. (Look for the `downloading` field on the `DBDatastoreStatus` to be false.) Yes, `getOrInsert` lets you set the record ID manually instead of getting an automatically-generated ID.